# Could not load WFS with bbox parameter using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wfs

I try to load a WFS including a bbox parameter via PyQGIS. The WFS is loaded without problems, but unfortunately the bbox parameter does not work. If the bbox parameter is added to the query I get all the results, including the results that are outside of the bbox range. When I start the request in the browser or using the QGIS GUI, I get the correctly filtered features. It looks like PyQGIS does not take into account the bbox parameter.

My code looks like this:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:arrondissement&COUNT=1000&SRSNAME=EPSG::4326&BBOX=42.374778,-2.109375,47.115000,2.856445", 'water', 'WFS')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Is this a known bug or something missing in my request?

As already said, in the browser or via the QGIS GUI the request works, but not with PyQGIS.

Comment: QGIS Version is 2.18.18

Comment: It's difficult to see how PyQGIS doesn't take BBOX into account, since the request is processed on the server and results returned to you. Looking at the [WFS 1.0.0 spec](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=7176), it appears that SRS is not used on a BBOX, and I have a feeling that only one CRS is supported too, which is why there's no need for CRS/SRS in the BBOX!  You say the query works in QGIS so perhaps QGIS is sending a WFS 1.1.0 request?

Answer (score 0):

You must give the bbox srs as well.

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("http://geoserver_url/ows?style=&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=1.0.0&typeName=dataset:water&bbox=3562017.31020000018179417,5679733.8194363797083497,3563253.31000480009242892,5681088.4972945200279355,EPSG:31467&srsname='EPSG:31467'", 'water', 'WFS')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately that does not work either.